# Which is best & secured way for saving login parameters ? Session or cookies ?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have been using Cookies in my website for logging in and logging out !

Now I am planning to include *"money transactions"* in my website, so I would like to keep the customer data in a secured manner.

So can some one help me to suggest the best way for handling this ?

```
Which can be better, sessions or cookies ?
```

Comment: What do you mean by login parameters? You're not storing usernames and passwords in a cookie are you?

Comment: Sessions use cookies! You will have to be more precise to make a distinction between them.

Comment: If you are considering storing financial information but asking questions about security, you may want to consider bringing in a developer with more experience to help you develop it.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641958/secure-sessions-cookies-in-php

Comment: Sessions/cookies, **plus** not to mention an [**SSL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer) certificate. I won't buy anything on the web, yet alone put in my `cc` number if I know I'm not on a secure `https` connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions. You will only store a random key on the client's computer and all sensitive data will stay on your server. No leaking possible, no copying possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions. Using cookies for logging in and logging out is fine (not recommended though). As you say for money transactions sessions will be better rather best.

Comment: Cookies are mostly used for 'Remember me' functionality?